# Changing value of method in different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My use-case:

Most use cases within the app require a normal call of the method `homepage`.

```
 class Obj
  def homepage
    @homepage ||= ancestors.detect do |ancestor|
      ancestor.is_a?(Homepage)
    end.presence || Homepage.default
  end
 end
```

`Obj` is the parent class of all other Models.
Within `Obj` the navigation is defined based on the `homepage`.
Obj.homepage is used quiet often within other Models/Views.

This is fine until I have to use a class called `News`

This class should not render the navigation based on the Obj.homepage but on the session.
I update the homepage session-hash unless the class is News.

```
   class CmsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :session_based_homepage
      def session_based_homepage
        unless news_page?
          @homepage = homepage_session
        end
      end
    end
```

I want to override the value of `Obj.homepage` within the model/controller of the news_pages obj-class
setting the session equal to the overriden homepage method. 
This way all other calls of `Obj.homepage` are still functioning but are based on the value of the session.

Afaik this should be possible with a setter in the Controller but I am too dumb.

Comment: Your requirement seems to be confusing. If you can explain it with an example case as to what you are trying to actually achieve, we may be able to help.

Comment: You are totally right, I updated my use-case hopefully it easier to follow now